# set array to property of a structure

Tags: c#

I'm using C#. Trying to do a structure with array property. It is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3

{
    struct Dummy
    {
        public bool one;
        public string two;
        public int[] three;

        public Dummy(bool o, string t, int[] th)
        {
            one = o; two=t; three=th;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           int[] K = {5,2};
           Dummy d = new Dummy(true, "mnm", K);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", d.one, d.two, d.three);

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }   
}
```

However d.three is System.Int32[] but not {5, 2}. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you implicitly convert an array to a string it will just write out its type. You’ll have to write the numbers out yourself how you want them to be. The variable has he correct values.

Comment: Just in case you don't know, you are passing a *reference* to the array to your `Dummy d` struct, which means if later you set `K[0] = 7`, then that effectively also automatically sets `d.three[0] = 7`, since both `d.three` and `K` are pointing to the same array in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `Console.WriteLine` will call the `ToString()` on object of `int[]` for the parameter `d.three` and it will return the type name actually, so you would need to convert the all array items in to a concatenated string, you can use `String.Join` here:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", d.one, d.two, String.Join(",",d.three));
```

Now this will give the expected output which would be comma separated array items.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to print an array you need to enumerate each element of the array.
If you pass it to a function that expects a string like your *Console.WriteLine* then it calls the ToString method on that array.
But the array class doesn't implement the ToString method and calls the base class *object.ToString()* method. That final method just prints the name of the class

Instead you could use *string.Join* that enumerates the array and join the results in a string:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", d.one, d.two, 
     "{" + string.Join(",", d.three) + "}");
```

Answer (score 0):

PrintArray(int[] array). There iterate over each element and stringify it.